# Install ATI Chipset Drivers when Using Nvidia Card?

Tags: drivers, motherboard, chipset, amd-graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I bought a new motherboard (with integrated ATI graphics) that came with ATI drivers for the chipset. Should I install the chipset drivers even though I am using an Nvidia graphics card in the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should, the chip set drivers should cover the motherboard devices, the NIC, the USB, and the SATA devices, etc.

You don't necessarily need to install the ATI graphics drivers for the board if they are installed separately (and you're not using the integrated graphics of course)